# How to Create Control and Event from Out side the form C#

Tags: c#, class

How to Create Control and Event from Out side the form C#

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }


    class  Methods 
    {
        //need to create method to Form 1 From herer
    }

    class EventHandler
    {
        //need to create EventHandler to Form 1 From herer
    }

    class CreateControl
    {
        //dynamically Create controls for Form1 From this class
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? While it is absolutely possible, I don't see any value in it

Comment: What do you mean by "create method to Form 1 from here"?  What are you actually trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: Create a concrete implementation of `Form1`, then using reflection, add methods and handlers. You will need a factory class to generate an instance of the concrete implementation of `Form1` and then use reflection to add methods and handlers. Considering the sparse nature of your question, I suggest you read this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, if I've understood you right:

```
  Form myForm = ...

  // Let's create a button on myForm
  Button myButton = new Button() {
    Text = "My Button",           //TODO: specify all the properties required here 
    Size = new Size(75, 25),
    Location = new Point(30, 40),
    Parent = myForm,              // Place on myForm instance
  };

  // We can implement an event with a help of lambda
  myButton.Click += (s, ea) => { 
    //TODO: put relevant code here
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't see any benefit in doing so, this would be what you want:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Methods.Init(this);
        }
    }


    class  Methods 
    {
        //need to create method to Form 1 From herer
        public static void Init(Form frm)
        {
            frm.Controls.Add((new CreateControl()).CreateButton("Test"));
        }
    }

    class EventHandlerWrapper
    {
        //need to create EventHandler to Form 1 From herer
        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TEST");
        }
    }

    class CreateControl
    {
        public Button CreateButton(string text)
        {
             EventHandlerWrapper e = new EventHandlerWrapper();
             Button btn = new Button();
             btn.Text = text;
             btn.Click += e.button_Click;
        }
    }    
}
```